# DataTable no es una función en laravel

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

Tengo un problema al momento de llamar la función DataTable en un script dentro de una vista, a pesar de que creo que estoy importando los archivos de la manera correcta nada que me coje los datos

NOTA: el archivo jquery.js no es la libreria como tal, si no, un archivo donde pongo las funciones generales, La libreria jquery la estoy llamando como cdn

Contenido del HEADER

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- CSRF Token -->
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">

    <title>{{ config('app.name', 'Laravel') }}</title>

    <!-- Scripts -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('js/jquery.js') }}" defer></script>
    <!-- Fonts -->
    <link rel="dns-prefetch" href="//fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Styles -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ asset('css/semantic.min.css') }}">
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.4.1/semantic.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="{{ asset('css/login.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
```

Contenido del BODY

```
{{-- scripts --}}
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('js/semantic.min.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('js/datatables.min.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('js/dataTables.semanticui.min.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('js/fixedHeader.semanticui.js') }}"></script>
@yield('scripts')
```

Script de la vista

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#programs').DataTable();});
```

Y este es el error

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si me podrian dar una mano con eso

Comment: Hola que tal, intenta usando los CDN:
https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js
https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js
https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js

Si funciona con los CDN, el error esta en la importacion de tus script

Comment: Sigue fallando aún con los cdn, ya llevo intentando un buen rato y nada, no se que pasa

Comment: En la misma web de ellos veras que hay veces que lo ponen en minusculas

Comment: Todavia nada, ya he movido hasta lo he puesto dentro de la vista blade

Answer (score 0):

Puede que tu script `js/datatables.min.js` no sea correcto.

Prueba lo siguiente:
Para el estilo `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">`

Y el script `<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>`

También puedes probar a añadir estas dos lineas en el head junto con `js/app.js` y `js/jquery.js`

Answer (score 0):

Ya pude solucionar, Tuve que incluir los archivos datatables en app.js despues de bootstrap

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

lo que veo es que algunos estilos del semantic ui no los lee, pero ya pude solucionar
muchas gracias a todos